# Inheritance not working as intended

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, typeof

Classes `Enemy` and `Ore` are childs of `Entity` class. Class `Asteroid` is child of `Enemy`. Code below is fired when my ship touches any of entities.

Code in a couple sentences is: When ship touches an ore, add ore to ship's inventory and remove that ore from screen. When ship touches enemy, check what enemy it is. If it's asteroid, push ship back, lower it's health and delete that asteroid.

```
if (entities[j] is Ore)
{ pilots[i].Ship.InventoryAdd(entities[j]); entities.RemoveAt(j--); }

if (entities[j] is Enemy)
{
    if(entities[j] is Asteroid)
    {
        pilots[i].Ship.AddForce(entities[j].Force * (entities[j] as Enemy).Damage);
        pilots[i].Ship.HP -= (entities[j] as Enemy).Damage;
        entities.RemoveAt(j);
    }
}
```

**NOTE** that i see the problem that can be triggered when in one update or frame, both collisions are happening (ship vs asteroid & ship vs ore), and I will fix this. Also, this is the whole code, not just a part of all cases. For now, I do only have ores and asteroids (and a ship) on screen.

Problem is happening in ship vs ore collision. My ship is pushed back. But I do that only on ship vs asteroid. That means that the program sees ore as asteroid, wich it is not. I checked all these things multiple times. Yes, they both have the same parent, but if I ask if an instance is asteroid, how on earth can he say "yes, and it's an ore too", when it's not.

I get that if I asked for an Asteroid instance, if it is of class Entity and Enemy and Asteroid, I would always get an answer "yes", but how can Ore be Asteroid?

**Question is:** what is logic behind this and how do I check this in proper way? Also note that line for adding force will fire for all Enemies, not just for Asteroids, which is the case for now.

Comment: What logic it is? The logic is yours only :-) In case of `Ore` you change the `entities` so that the index `j` most probably doesn't point to an `Ore` any longer

Comment: Why do you assume that inheritance is somehow broken? Have you tried debugging the code? Why do you assume that eg `entitiers.RemoveAt` will leave `entities[j]` pointing to the same instance?

Comment: If you use `is` keyword, in the most cases your code have design issues.

Comment: It would be so much better if you define a `Collision` event on your base class and have each type implement handlers.

Comment: @Monset please, read how good questions are structured. Questions about inheritance shouldn't include loops. If there is a real issue, you can demonstrate it with just a few lines. On the other hand, modifying a collection while iterating it is asking for trouble. If inheritance was broken people would have noticed

Comment: @devnull yes, they do. I will not rewrite the note again here in comments. I see that error is there.

Comment: So why do you ask then?

Comment: @Monset, please provide a *minimal* and *complete* example that demonstrates your issue that doesn't require people to write a lot of classes to reproduce it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there are litelarly 4 classes, and everything is based on them. this is a *minimal* and *complete* example

Comment: It is not, you did not mention anywhere the exact content of your `entities` array. If you happen to have Ores at two consecutive indexes, you might have never noticed the issue :-)

Comment: @Monset and as everyone pointed out, you had an indexing problem. This is neither minimal nor compelte though. It won't compile. If it did though, it wouldn't exhibit the problem Even if you were right and there *was* an inheritance bug, we wouldn't be able to reproduce it. PS *I* didn't downvote, but almost anyone else did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dealing with two different elements in the `entities` array. Because you remove the entry from the array, the second `if` works on a different element.

Resolve this by using `else if`

```
if (entities[j] is Ore)
{ 
  pilots[i].Ship.InventoryAdd(entities[j]); entities.RemoveAt(j--); 
}
else if (entities[j] is Enemy)
{
    if(entities[j] is Asteroid)
    {
        pilots[i].Ship.AddForce(entities[j].Force * (entities[j] as Enemy).Damage);
        pilots[i].Ship.HP -= (entities[j] as Enemy).Damage;
        entities.RemoveAt(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply *avoid* using `entities[j]` all over the place. Just assign the content to a temporary variable

Comment: This works perffectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You remove the object at index "j", and recheck entities[j] afterwards. So if there is Ore at 8 and an Astroid at 9, you remove the Ore putting the Astroid at 8 before the 2nd if.

Comment: Please read the big ass **NOTE** I wrote

Comment: @Monset Please read and understand the comments and answers

Comment: @Monset Maarten is right, you need to understand what he is saying

Answer (score 4):

You may want to change the second if to an else if. Right now what happens is that if your ship collides with ore it will add the ore to the inventory (as intended), and then decrease the index into your entities array by one.

*After* that decrease, you check if the entity at the current index is an enemy, so you're basically looking at a completely different entity as you did before.

Changing the second check to

```
else if (entities[j] is Enemy)
```

should prevent that.

Hope this helps,

Frauke

Answer (score 3):

Ok lets say you have this situation:

j=8 is an Ore that you are colliding with
j=7 is an Asteriod that you are NOT colliding with

Because you do j-- after processing an Ore, then entities[j] will now be pointing at an Asteriod *even though there was no collision* with one. Then HP get subtracted etc.

You do not have an inheritance problem, you have a 'messing with loop variable during a loop' problem.

You could maybe do something like this:

```
if (entities[j] is Ore)
{ 
    pilots[i].Ship.InventoryAdd(entities[j]); 
    entityIndexesToRemove.add(j);
}

if (entities[j] is Enemy)
{
    if(entities[j] is Asteroid)
    {
        pilots[i].Ship.AddForce(entities[j].Force * (entities[j] as Enemy).Damage);
        pilots[i].Ship.HP -= (entities[j] as Enemy).Damage;
        entityIndexesToRemove.add(j);
    }
}
// then rest of that loop on j ...

// then later when loop has finished we do removals....
for (int r=entitiesToRemove.Count; r>0;r--)
    entities.RemoveAt(entitiesToRemove[r]);
```

Comment: Check the answer I approved, and you'll see how it fixed my problem without changing the way I loop trough all entities

Comment: @Monset yes Nineberrys answer was good, but do you understand why it worked and what the original problem was?